# How do I install phpize on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: php, php7

I am quite new to Linux and I need to install phpize on my Ubuntu 15.10. I am running PHP 7.0.4 (XAMPP). Does anyone have a clue how to do that? I would really appreciate any help from you guys.

Comment: You question was already answered... Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108937/how-to-install-and-run-phpize

Answer (score 1):

Just run the command

```
apt-get install php70-dev
```